# Windows Batch won't let me break long "FOR" loop into multiple lines?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
FOR /F %a in (downloadlist.txt) DO (
SET url=%a
&& SET suffix=%url:ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all=% 
&& SET combined=%url%%suffix%
&& SET a_link=%combined%%assembly%
&& echo %a_link%
&& SET t_link=%combined%%transcripts%
&& SET cds_link=%combined%%CDS%
&& SET p_link=%combined%%protein%
&& WGET %a_link%
&& WGET %t_link%
&& WGET %cds_link%
&& WGET %p_link%
)
```

How can i break this up into multiple lines? This is what I have currently and it doesn't work. I've also tried using the ^ character. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Do you get an error message? Does it run the commands in the wrong order? What?

Comment: Whenever i tried running it in CMD, i would get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: use `%%a` instead of `%a`.%a is for command prompt only.Batch files needs double % in loops

Comment: @npocmaka, i use %a because i paste the code into command prompt

Comment: @Ambushes - yes.But in batch files loops uses double %. single one os for the command prompt only.

Comment: I know... i'm having issues whenever I paste it into command prompt to troubleshoot for errors. I change it to double % in the batch file. The issue is i'm getting invalid syntax even for the SET commands.

Comment: Why do you even need `&&` at all? `set` isn't going to fail.

Comment: That's true. I still need && for the last four statements though. I'll give it a try with removing those &&s.

Comment: If you are executing your code in command prompt, why did you tag your question with [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: Does it matter? The point is it isn't working. The error is the same whether you run it in CMD or as a batch file.

Comment: You assign variables inside a loop, so you must use [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: You information is incomplete. You get certain variables from nowhere, like _assembly, transcripts, CDS, protein_. Pls post the entire content of your _downloadlist.txt_ file in its original formatting, and also the batch section that defines these variables.

Answer (score 1):

Replace unknown variable values *assembly, transcripts, CDS, protein* with your real values, save this script to a file *test.bat* and run it from Cmd window. Post exact error message if any.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "assembly=1" & set "transcripts=2" & set "CDS=3" & set "protein=4"
FOR /F %%a in (downloadlist.txt) DO (
    SET url=%%a
    SET suffix=!url:ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all=!
    SET combined=!url!!suffix!
    SET a_link=!combined!%assembly%
    echo !a_link!
    SET t_link=!combined!%transcripts%
    SET cds_link=!combined!%CDS%
    SET p_link=!combined!%protein%
    WGET !a_link! && WGET !t_link! && WGET !cds_link! && WGET !p_link!
)
exit /b
```

Comment: @Ambushes If the script works for you, consider upvoting AND accepting any answer in this thread by clicking "Arrow Up" and "Select" signs to the left of the answer. :)